# if else stament in php

Tags: php, if-statement

Good Day. Here my question:
i want to display the result if the count get from the SQL is more than 0, if the count is 0, then the result will not display.
Here the current output after adding if else statement in my php :

```
    {"result":[]}
```

This is the output before adding if else statement in my php:

```
 { "result": [
    {"day":"1","count":"0"},
    {"day":"2","count":"2"},
    {"day":"3","count":"0"},
    {"day":"4","count":"0"}....
```

I want the result only like tis :

```
    {"result":[
      {"day":"2","count":"2"}
    ]}
```

Here my php code:

```
define('HOST','xx');
define('USER','xx');
define('PASS','xx');
define('DB','x');


//$month = $_POST['month'];
//$year = $_POST['year'];

$month = 10;
$year=2016;

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

$result = array();
 for ($day=1 ; $day<=31 ; $day++) {
     $sql = "select count(entryID) from Entry where
         EXTRACT(DAY FROM(entryTime)) = '$day'  AND
         EXTRACT(MONTH FROM(entryTime)) = '$month' AND 
         EXTRACT(YEAR FROM(entryTime))= '$year'";
     $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if($row[0] >0)
     $day2 = (string)$day;
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
         array_push($result,
         array('day' =>$day2,
            'count' => $row[0]
         ));

         }
}

 }


 echo $appear . json_encode(array("result"=>$result));



mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: your conditional `if($row[0] >0)` needs to be inside your loop `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))`, not before/outside, as `$row` is only defined inside the `while()` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Your Variable `$row` within your Conditional Check Block `if($row[0] > 0) {` was not yet defined at the Point where it was used. In other words; the entire Conditional Logic should be moved into the `while` Loop Construct...
> Perhaps, the snippet below sheds some light:

```
<?php

    define('HOST','xx');
    define('USER','xx');
    define('PASS','xx');
    define('DB','x');


    $con    = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);
    $month  = 10;
    $year   = 2016;
    $result = array();
    /****************************|
    | $month  = $_POST['month']; |
    | $year   = $_POST['year'];  |
    |****************************/


    for($day=1; $day<=31; $day++) {
        $sql    = " SELECT COUNT(entryID) ";
        $sql   .= " FROM Entry WHERE ";
        $sql   .= " EXTRACT( DAY FROM(entryTime) )      = '$day'   ";
        $sql   .= " AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM(entryTime))  = '$month' ";
        $sql   .= " AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM(entryTime))   = '$year'  ";
        $res    = mysqli_query($con,$sql);  

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
            if($row[0] > 0) {        //<== CONDITIONAL LOGIC HERE, INSTEAD
                $day2 = (string)$day;
                array_push($result,
                    array('day'     => $day2,
                          'count'   => $row[0]
                    )
                );
            }
        }
    }   

    //NOTICE: THE $appear VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED IN YOUR CODE. 
    echo $appear . json_encode(array("result"=>$result));   
    mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: it worked! ty:D the $appear is before i used to test somethings. i forgt to remove it :D thank you!